# Creating has_many relationships in ActiveRecord without :primary_key

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm working with an older version of Rails and ActiveRecord that does not have the `:primary_key` option in `has_many` relationships of more recent ActiveRecord versions and unfortunately I don't get to control when we upgrade.  Is there any way to hack this solution via `:conditions` or `:finder_sql` options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible using `:finder_sql` e.g.

```
has_many :foobars, :finder_sql => 'select * from table where foreign_key = #{primary_key}'
```

Note the use of single quotes around the query so that `#{primary_key}` is not expanded at the time when the association is declared.